# Microclimate Pod CrashLoopBackOff in IBM Cloud Private

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, microclimate

I'm trying to deploy IBM Microclimate to IBM Cloud Private CE 2.1.0.3, as described in the documentation (https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/stable/ibm-microclimate/README.md), but the Microclimate pod status shows CrashLoopBackOff and the Portal is not accessible (it shows a 503 Service Unavailable error in the browser). I tried looking at the logs for the pod, but that is not possible either. Has anyone faced an issue like this one before? Any hints on how to troubleshoot or solve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot of information to go on. If you'd like some more interactive help do please ask in our Slack channel as per https://microclimate-dev2ops.github.io/community. If you want to debug it here, can you please post the results of: `kubectl get pods`, `kubectl get ing`, `kubectl describe pods`, `helm list --tls`, `kubectl get deployments -o yaml`. If you installed to a non-default namespace, please add `--namespace [your-mc-ns]` to each command.

Comment: Hi Mark, the output for the commands where too big to post them here, so I created a file with the results and uploaded to Box. Please let me know if you can access the file: https://app.box.com/s/9pqrzm78i3v1nd5x2l5qu4if4bjcuq0v. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, the useful information from the crashing pod is, ` Warning  Failed          ... failed to start container "microclimate-portal": Error response from daemon: linux mounts: path /var/run is mounted on /run but it is not a shared or slave mount`
The chart is trying to mount /var/run from the host to /var/run within the Filewatcher pod. Which operating system have you installed ICP onto? This might be https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61058 - see the comment by jsafrane on March 13th - that may fix this.

Comment: The same error is seen further up: "
Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      linux mounts: path /var/run is mounted on /run but it is not a shared or slave mount"

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the answer. I'm using the Vagrant image for ICP CE 2.1.0.3 posted here: https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md. It uses Ubuntu 16.04 as OS. I'm running on VirtualBox 5.2.12 on Mac 10.12. According to the post you referenced, what it needs to be done is to "add a new service or add a command to Kubernetes init script before running Docker" that runs "mount --make-rshared /run". I'm new to ICP world and we are trying to demo ICP/Microclimate to a customer, so any guidance on how to do that?

Comment: Hello, I've not used the Vagrant image for a while. I'm asking internally amongst my colleagues in ICP; I'm sorry but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help. If you get any feedback from your ICP colleagues I appreciate sharing it here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the command "mount --make-rshared /run" to the Vagrant file for the ICP CE image solves this issue and Microclimate is able to be installed successfully. Reference: https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/issues/139